Formatting last_viewed_at filter in Looker Python SDK
I'm struggling to filter dashboards by last_viewed_at using the Looker API. I want to retrieve dashboards viewed in the last two years. Here’s the basic code I’m using:
# looker_sdk==24.10.0

import looker_sdk
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

sdk = looker_sdk.init40(...)

two_years_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=730)
formatted_date = two_years_ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

dashboards = sdk.search_dashboards(
    limit=10,
    sorts="view_count desc",
    fields="id,title,view_count,last_viewed_at",
    last_viewed_at=f">={formatted_date}"
)

I've also tried various other date formats, but no luck. If I remove last_viewed_at, I get dashboards with dates from this and last year.
Any advice on the correct format or syntax? Thanks!
